# Rendering the same model in multiple WPF Viewports

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, 3d, modeling

I am working on a WPF application which has 4 viewports.  I build a 3D model which is fairly complex and contains 50,000-100,000 Triangles.  I then want to display the same 3D model in all 4 viewports.  The way I am doing this, it takes about 10 seconds for the model to display in all 4 viewports (which are actually HelixViewports, from the Helix 3D Toolkit for WPF).  I have never used multi threading, but I am thinking this may be a good idea.  I need the models to render in all 4 viewports in less than 2 seconds.  I am probably writing my code inefficiently as well, a sample is below.  Thanks for your help!

Render() function (C#):

```
//Each Viewport must have it's own ModelVisual3D
        ModelVisual3D renderModel = new ModelVisual3D();
        ModelVisual3D renderModel2 = new ModelVisual3D();
        ModelVisual3D renderModel3 = new ModelVisual3D();
        ModelVisual3D renderModel4 = new ModelVisual3D();

        Model3DGroup modelGroup = new Model3DGroup();

        //Here is an example of the 2 different ways 
        //I add components to the Models:

        //Add the cylinder to the viewport 
        if (isCylinder)
        {

            //Each viewport must have its' own 
            PipeVisual3D ballBat = dO.getRound();
            PipeVisual3D ballBat2, ballBat3, ballBat4;
            ballBat2 = new PipeVisual3D();
            ballBat2.Content = ballBat.Content;
            ballBat3 = new PipeVisual3D();
            ballBat3.Content = ballBat.Content;
            ballBat4 = new PipeVisual3D();
            ballBat4.Content = ballBat.Content;

            this.mainViewport.Children.Add(ballBat);
            this.mainViewport2.Children.Add(ballBat2);
            this.mainViewport3.Children.Add(ballBat3);
            this.mainViewport4.Children.Add(ballBat4);
        }

        //OR this way:

        //Add inner top wane to the viewport
        if (isTopWane)
        {
            modelGroup.Children.Add(dO.getTopWane());

        }

        //Add inner bottom wane to the viewport
        if (isBottomWane)
        {
            modelGroup.Children.Add(dO.getBottomWane());
        }

        //Then, at the end of all my IF checks, this is how I
        //'Draw' the models into the viewports:

        //Each ModelVisual3D has the same content
        renderModel2.Content = renderModel.Content;
        renderModel3.Content = renderModel.Content;
        renderModel4.Content = renderModel.Content;




        //"Paint" the viewports
        this.mainViewport.Children.Add(renderModel);
        this.mainViewport2.Children.Add(renderModel2);
        this.mainViewport3.Children.Add(renderModel3);
        this.mainViewport4.Children.Add(renderModel4);
```

Also, it may help to know that I am testing this app on a laptop with 16GB ram, a core i7
processor, and an NVIDIA Quadro 3000M graphics card.  I have been searching for ways to speed up my app and will continue to do so, if anyone has a suggestion or can point me to useful information it will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have been able to speed up my app significantly, but it is still too slow.  I now have 2 large viewports instead of 4 smaller ones, both show the same model.  I also was able to get my triangle count down to 30,000-45,000 triangles, depending on the model which results form a scan.  Rendering these models into both viewports now takes about 3.2-4.0 seconds.  My goal is to get below 1.5 seconds.  I also did these things: Removed normal vectors from my triangles, changed some methods I wrote so that each triangle is a GeometryModel3D instead of a Model3DGroup containing 1 child (the triangle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you put your entire model in one GeometryModel3D? You have 35000-40000 triangles, it means that you have 35000-40000 GeometryModel3D!? That's huge...

You should have one Visual (which equals a scene or a model containing multiple parts) containing a Model3DGroup, containing as many GeometryModel3D as you have models (and not triangles!). Each GeometryModel3D containing a MeshGeometry3D which contains all the triangles, indices, normales, uv coords of one model.

Comment: This was exactly the problem.  I figured it out a while ago but didn't post it here (I posted it in another question).  Thanks!  I now have another concern, though- What if I want to use greyscale information to color each triangle differently?  Is this possible while having all the triangles in a MeshGeometry3D?  I know I define the color of the MODEL not on the MESH.  Anyway, thanks for your answer!