# Multiple viewport with same model in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d

I referenced from this [Rendering the same model in multiple WPF Viewports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16191985/rendering-the-same-model-in-multiple-wpf-viewports)

I'm a wpf beginner and have the similar question with that link. I want to show three models which would move relatively and show in different viewport with different camera setting.

At first I tried to add ModelVisual3D to different viewport, and it didn't work obviously.

So I tried to do this below, here is the code:

```
Model3DGroup model1 = read(path1);
Model3DGroup model2 = read(path2);
Model3DGroup model3 = read(path3);

modelVisual1.Content = model1 ;
modelVisual2.Content = model2 ;
modelVisual3.Content = model3 ;

mainModelVisual.Children.Add(modelVisual1);
mainModelVisual.Children.Add(modelVisual2);
mainModelVisual.Children.Add(modelVisual3);

Viewport1.Children.Add(mainModelVisual);
```

The reason why I don't use just one Model3DGroup is that I have assign different 
`Transform3D` and I will add the hittest in future.(Is that a appropriate reason?)

And now I want to add the model to different viewport like this:

```
otherMainModelVisual2.Content = mainModelVisual.Content;
otherMainModelVisual3.Content = mainModelVisual.Content;

Viewport2.Children.Add(otherMainModelVisual2);
Viewport3.Children.Add(otherMainModelVisual3);
```

The **viewport1** will show the model normally, but other viewport didn't show anything.

The question is why I can't do this like the link?
Or do I have to copy two models and add to different modelvisual like the **viewport1**?

I'm a beginner, hope anyone could show me in simple code.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the first comment in the code of the question you referenced, each `Viewport3D` must have its own `ModelVisual3D`. However, to be more clear:

In WPF, a `Visual`, including a `Visual3D`, can only exist in one place in the Visual Tree. To put it another way, a `Visual` can only have one parent. Your Window (or whatever) is the root of the Tree. So you'll have something like this:

```
Window
|
|--Grid
   |
   |--ViewPort1
      |
      |--mainModelVisual
         |
         |--modelVisual1
         |--modelVisual2
         |--modelVisual3
   |
   |--ViewPort2
   |--ViewPort3
```

The reason you are only seeing the model in the first viewport is that the modelVisual1, modelVisual2, and modelVisual3, which are all `Visual3D` objects, have been assigned as (grand)children of ViewPort1. Assigning them as children of more than one thing simply won't work. When you assign them to be the child of the mainModelVisual, you are locking their place in the Visual Tree, until such time as you remove them.

Notice, however, that the model1, model2, and model3 elements are not shown on the tree. This is because they are not `Visual3D` objects, but rather `ModelGroup3D` objects, which is a kind of content, essentially data that *instructs* the Visual objects on how to draw themselves. You can assign the models to as many `ModelVisual3D` objects as you'd like. This is what's happening in the linked question. The same content is being used multiple times, but each `ViewPort3D` has a unique set of `Visual` objects assigned to it.

You would have the same problem if, for example, you created a `Button` and tried to add it to two different `StackPanel` objects. Only one `StackPanel` would render the button. You could make two different buttons though, and they could both have the same text, assigned from the same `string` variable.

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation! Now I share the Model3DGroup to the three viewports and it work!